# LLVM cannot see static function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, llvm

I am trying to instrument the linux kernel code to insert a function call in every function right after a `BitCast` instruction.

So I modify the C code to `#include <linux/my_header.h>` where I have my printer function.

The header looks something like this.

```
#ifndef __header_ID
#define __header_ID

static inline void print_typecast(...){
    printk(...);
}
#endif
```

Then I use Xclang to load my FunctionPass, which looks something like this.

```
// M is of type llvm::Module*
Function* f = M->getFunction("print_typecast");
if (f == nullptr) {
    errs() << "Function not found in the module\n";
}
else {
    // insert function in the code
}
```

However, my pass never finds the function in the module. When I remove the `static` it will find the function but then the linker in the final compilation step will complain of duplicate definition.

Anyone knows how to make LLVM "see" static imported/included functions?

Edit: I have also gone to the extreme where I have the same function directly written in every c file of the kernel code (the ones that `#include <linux/kernel.h>`)

Comment: How is `getFunction()` implemented?  You question is not complete.  Also, just what do you think `static inline` does?

Comment: If getFunction is returning a pointer to the function I'm not sure how you're able to do that with a static inline function. Since inline is defined directly in the function its being called in..

Comment: @AndrewHenle @Yuumi  getFunction is part of LLVM. Check `llvm::Module`. The getFunction returns a pointer to a function that is visible by that Module. From what I read `static` means that the function is only usable by the file it was declared in and `inline` means that you can replace the `call` instruction with the body of the function (which i expect the compiler to automatically do after my pass).

Comment: @anon *`inline` means that you can replace the call instruction with the body of the function*  And how would you get the address of a function if it's been inlined?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I dont think `Function*` is the address of the function from the output of the compilation. It's just a pointer to what LLVM uses to identify a function in the module. Also if it is what you said then removing `static` would still not find the Function in the Module, **but it does** even though its still inlined.

Comment: Is printk static inlined too? If not can you not just call getFunction("printk")?

Comment: You could try just removing the `inline`, but leaving it `static`. Then there should be at most one copy of the function body in each compilation unit that includes the header (but it may get optimized out if not referenced elsewhere in the compilation unit). I do not know if your `getFunction` can find internally linked (`static`) functions or not, so it might not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` means that all calls to this function will be visible to *this* compiller *now*, and by implication that if the compiler sees no such calls, then it can skip compiling any output for the function, because you as programmer have promised that noone will want it.

Comment: Does this mean that if there is no call to the function that the optimizer will remove it? That's why I'm not seeing the static function? So if it's not `static` then the optimizer doesn't know if the function is called from somewhere else so it won't be deleted?

Comment: Well, it's not "removed by the optimizer", it's simply not generated at all by the frontend. But that is why you're not seeing it, yes.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I was able to get the function to appear in the LLVM IR after adding 1 function call. I will still need to mess with the front-end to scale this up but at least I know what is going on. Thank you again!

Comment: As a note to further confirm what you said. The static function will not appear even in O0, so it's not an optimizer dead code elimination pass.